# jQuery snow plugin does not show the same amount of snow on all pages

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a simple jQuery snow falling plugin on my site: [JQuery-Snowfall](https://github.com/loktar00/JQuery-Snowfall)

If you take a look at the homepage, less snow shows then if you look at another page.

The following code is in the `js/script.js` file, and is used by every page.

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $(document).snowfall({image :"images/assets/flake.png", minSize: 6,maxSize:25,flakeCount:150});
});
```

Homepage, less snow: [Click here](https://tetocserepem.hu/)

Other page on this site, more snow: [Click here](https://tetocserepem.hu/letoltheto-dokumentumok)

Comment: What's the problem again?

Comment: Not enough snow probably

Comment: Both pages have 150 flakes, just run `document.querySelectorAll(".snowfall-flakes").length` in console to see. Pretty sure it's because the homepage has more content so it appears that less are visible at once (due to the window size)

Comment: I think the plugin uses the width and the height of the webpage to calculate the amount of snowflakes, on taller pages it looks like there's less snow because they are more separated (also de plugin breakes the height of the home page, snowflakes don't disappear, they fall and make the home page taller and taller). I guess you'll have better help asking the author.

Comment: And I know it's not related, but I would give a second thought to that whole snow thing, it takes away the focus from the content (text & images) of the website

Comment: I guess you can check width and height and use a different amount of flakes depending on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both pages have 150 snowflakes, however, the document height of the homepage is larger then that of the others. This means different number of snowflakes are visible within the viewport.

To get around this, you can add a div to the body that takes up the entire viewport. You can then apply the snowflakes to this div, rather then the document.

I don't know about your limitations here so here's a JS only solution:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    var snowfallDiv = $(document.body).append("<div style='height: 100%;width: 100%;left: 0;top: 0;position: fixed;'></div>");

    snowfallDiv.snowfall({image: "images/assets/flake.png", minSize: 6, maxSize: 25, flakeCount: 150});
});
```

If you can edit the page properly, I would suggest putting the div in your HTML.

Here's a working example:

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {

  $("#snowfall").snowfall();
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  height: 250px;
}

#snowfall {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/JQuery-Snowfall/1.7.4/snowfall.jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="height:5000px"></div>

<div id="snowfall"></div>
```